# What is the filepath for a file within a package?

Tags: html, css, r, fonts, r-package

I am writing a package that sets some fonts in a css script so that it can be reused in markdown/shiny reporting. The custom package function that I am asking about is as follows - it sets the `h1` headers and `p` text as Clarke Regular & Clarke Black fonts. Both the font files are uploaded into the `inst` folder of the package.

However, when I call font() in a simple Hello World shiny app after downloading the package from GitHub, the font doesn't load! Is there a problem with the file path for the fonts - how do I source the font files that I have uploaded into the `inst` folder?

```
#' Add together two numbers
#' @importFrom shiny tags
#' @export fonts
#'

fonts <- function(){

  shiny::tags$style(
    HTML(paste0("

      @font-face {
          src: url('", system.file("Clarke-Regular.otf", package = "XXThemes"), "');
          font-family: 'Clarke-Regular';
      }

      @font-face {
          src: url('", system.file("Clarke-Black.otf", package = "XXThemes"), "');
          font-family: 'Clarke-Black';
      }



/* Body Colors and Background for Template */
/* ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ */


body {
  font-family: 'Clarke-Regular';
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Clarke-Black';
  font-size: 48px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Clarke-Regular';
  color: #000000;
}

ul {
  font-family: 'Clarke-Regular';
}

b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
    ")
    )
  )
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know whether this changes something, but I've always seen `font-family` followed by `src` in `@font-face`.

Comment: So the package in called "XXThemes"? What exactly does `system.file("Clarke-Regular.otf", package = "XXThemes")` return foryou? You are passing that as a `url()` but is it a URL? What operating system are you using? Are you running the shiny app only on your own machine?

Comment: Yes! I've censored the package name (as it's for the company I work for).  system.file returns the location of the font file in my local drive. I am using Windows and have only tested it locally on my own machine so far! @MrFlick

Comment: But what does that path look like exactly? Does it star with "c:\"? You can try prepending the URL with `file:\\` so it's a proper URL. If you check your developer tools you should be able to see if the request is being made in your browser and what the result is. It's possible access to the file may be blocked for security reasons. Normally you don't want web pages that are able to read any file on your computer if you happen to guess the path.